# Apache2 - Hosting two sites on the same domain with different ports

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, port, opensuse

I am hosting a staging site (test.mydomain.com) which currently work well on port 80 for two sites (test.mydomain.com and test.FRmydomain.com)

I am working on a new backend and I would like to deploy a third site on this server for testing.  My hope is that it will live at test.mydomain.com:4204.  I've got some experience with apache and quickly added statements:
Listen 4204
NameVirtualHost *:4204

and created a new config for my site.  What I imagine are the relevant parts of my config:

```
<VirtualHost *:4204 >
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    ServerName test.mydomain.com:4204
```

However, the site is not publicly available, by name or ip.  If i

```
curl localhost:4204
```

from the server, I get the expected page content

At this point, I'm a bit of a loss on how to go forwards.  It seems like my config is correct but not available to be served.  Am I better off defining a proxy definition so that, for instance:

```
test.mydomain.com/4204
```

proxies to my localhost server or is there a way to make the site available via the internet?

EDIT:
I have added an iptable rule after further Googling with the command:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 4204 -j ACCEPT
```

I can see apache listening on 4204 and the rule is definitely in place but cant reach the site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
"ServerName test.mydomain.com:4204"
```

to

```
"ServerName test.mydomain.com".
```

The first line in your example is specifying the port so you don't have to do it again.

Comment: I have done so and restarted apache, but no change :(

Comment: Can you post the complete virtual host settings?

Comment: Sorry guys....looks like my config was good.  The hosting provider had to open a port for me.